# Linear equation help

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1-x}{4} + \frac{5x+1}{2} = 3 - \frac{2(x+1)}{8}$$

I got x=1 but the book says x=4/5 and I don't understand how to get to that, I tried working backwards too but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's my work
using 8 as the lcm
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac 81(\frac {(1-x)}4) +  \frac 81(\frac {(5x+1)}2) &=  \frac 81(3) - \frac 81\frac {2(x+1)}8 \\
2(1-x) + 4(5x+1) &= 24 - 2x + 2 \\
2 - 2x + 20x + 4 &= 24 - 2x + 2 \\
6 + 18x &= 26 -2x \\
20x &= 20 \\
x &= 1 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: Multiply the whole equation by $8$ and see if that doesn't make it easier.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when formatting your questions.

Comment: you didn't distribute the $-$ sign in your second line of work; $-(2x+2) = -2x-2$

Comment: @AshleySmith Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sign mistake here
$$2(1-x) + 4(5x+1) = 24 - 2x \color{red}{+ 2}$$
It should be
$$2(1-x) + 4(5x+1) = 24 - 2x \color{blue}{- 2}$$

Because 
$$-\frac {2(x+1)}8 =-\frac x4-\frac 14$$

Comment: Thank you! now i get it :)

Comment: yw @AshleySmith .....

Answer (score 1):

Get everything over as a fraction with a denominator of $8$ and equate, so:

$$\frac{2(1-x)}{8}+\frac{4(5x+1)}{8}=\frac{24}{8}-\frac{2(x+1)}{8}$$

Thus we have:
$$2-2x+20x+4=24-2x-2$$

See if you can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{1-x}{4} + \frac{5x+1}{2} = 3 - \frac{2(x+1)}{8}\iff 2(1-x)+4(5x+1)=24-2(x+1)\\\iff2-2x+20x+4=24-2x-2\iff20x=16$$